# Count with condition-mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT pnumber, pname, COUNT(*)
FROM project 
INNER JOIN works_on ON pno=pnumber 
INNER JOIN department ON dnumber=dnum
GROUP BY pnumber
```

Right now, mysql will return the project number and name, along with the number of employees who are working on it. What I want to do is that mysql only count employees from department 5. In other words there are people from different departments working on projects, but I want only the ones from department 5 to be counted and not all.

Comment: Isn't that what `WHERE` clauses are for?

Comment: Nope, if I use where, it only returns results from projects in department 5. I want projects from all departments, but employee count only from department 5.

Comment: Then you're using the wrong column in the `WHERE` clause. It would help if you showed the schema. Why do projects have department numbers? People are in departments, projects aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Barmar's and Shafeeq's suggestion of using a `WHERE` clause won't work for you (for example, if you need to include all departments in your result, but only count people from department 5) you can use this:

```
 SUM(IF(dnum=5, 1, 0)) AS CountFromDepartment5
```

So we'd have:

```
SELECT pnumber, pname, COUNT(*) AS TotalCount,  SUM(IF(dnum=5, 1, 0)) AS CountFromDepartment5
FROM project 
INNER JOIN works_on ON pno=pnumber 
INNER JOIN department ON dnumber=dnum
GROUP BY pnumber
```

Comment: Thanks. This is just the way I want it. I was trying to use count just by itself, that's why I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `WHERE`

```
SELECT pnumber, pname, COUNT(*)
FROM project 
JOIN works_on ON pno = pnumber 
JOIN department ON dnumber=dnum
WHERE dnumber = 5
GROUP BY pnumber
```

**EDIT**

```
SELECT pnumber, pname, COUNT(*),SUM(IF(dnumber=5, 1, 0)) AS count5 
FROM project 
JOIN works_on ON pno = pnumber 
JOIN department ON dnumber=dnum
GROUP BY pnumber
```

Comment: I have already tried that, if I use where, it only returns results from projects in department 5. I want projects from all departments, but employee count only from department 5.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `WHERE` clause that specifies the department you want.

```
SELECT pnumber, pname, COUNT(*)
FROM project 
INNER JOIN works_on ON pno=pnumber 
WHERE dnumber = 5
GROUP BY pnumber
```

You don't need to join with `department`, since the department number also exists as a foreign key in the `works_on` table.